# SSH UNIX command

Tags: unix

I am running a shell script(which contains several UNIX commands) from DEV environment.
Now in this shell script i need to write a unix command to connect to a QA environment and go to a particular path over there to check for some files.

i am using below command to connect to QA environment through script:

```
ssh QA      ---- To connect to QA environment
cd a/b/c    ----- To execute this command under QA environment.
```

when i am executing a script, it is then asking me for a password to connect to QA environment and after entering password i am able to connect to QA.
BUT THE COMMAND 'cd a/b/c' IS NOT GETTING EXECUTED IN QA AFTER THAT.

Please suggest which command should i use in the unix script to connect to QA environment and execute some unix commands over there in a same script?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633750/ssh-with-command-plus-the-shell

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for executing a command on the host connected to with `ssh` is:

```
ssh user@host command
```

To execute command on the host and return:

```
ssh user@host 'cd /etc/ && echo fstab'
```

To execute command and stay connected to the host:

```
ssh user@host -t 'cd /etc && bash -i'
```

See `man ssh` for reference on your system.

Comment: Agree: the && is quite important to stop attempting execute if the cd failed.  You could also "cd && execute || echo trouble" to get a specific message if either failed.

Comment: Thanks people..above code is working..
but the real command which i want to execute is 'air tag' 
the above code is working perfectly for ls and cd commands.
but when i am trying 'air tag a.save' its showing me an error that 
'ksh: air:  not found'

Comment: @user3095778 That error means the `air` command either isn't installed or can't be found in the current path on the remote host.